# How right use SSIM loss pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, ssim

I don't understand how I can use this loss in my model. I saw official topic but it don't help me. Maybe I need to describe formulas from there. I have SegNet model

[SSIM from github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx1bj.png)

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Are you asking how to apply the SSIM function or where it should be used?

Comment: How to apply this loss, because i get bad result in classification